# Loadbalancer coming in pending state

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

I am deploying Ambassador as API gateway on Azure platform by using kubectl and getting same pending state on LoadBalancer.

I am following this link for setting ambassador:

https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-java-apps-with-kubernetes-and-the-ambass

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it takes around 5 minutes to provision networking stuff in Azure. If more than 15 minutes passed it is a pretty strong indicator your k8s is not properly configured to provision resource in Azure

you need to find which service principal k8s is using and grant proper credentials.
https://serverfault.com/questions/896673/how-to-find-the-service-principal-assigned-to-a-newly-created-aks-cluster
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/aks/kubernetes-service-principal.md

Comment: It is working fine when we are using Node app as an API gateway but it is not working when we are trying same with Ambassador API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You should tail the logs of `kube-controller-manager` pods on your cluster (if you have access to `kube-system` namespace) after you create a new load balancer.

Logs regarding Azure LB provisioning are found in that pod log. That's where I've mostly found reasons for LB not provisioning.